# Suitable header for search quicklinks

Tags: interface, copywriting

I'm working on a design for a site that helps users calculate how much tax they will have to pay for a given salary. I've included some quick links underneath the salary input, but I'm struggling to think of a header that explains what these links are. Currently, the header is **Browse salaries** but I don't think this best explains the purpose of this section. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: what specific info does the user get by clicking the link? Does it lead them to a page, or is it interactive? And if they know their own salary, why have all the brackets there? Wouldn't you just input, calculate, and see the results?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the user will be able to view tax rates by a given salary range.

In that case, the information is not about receiving **Salary information** but **Tax rate information**.

I also put 'Annual' for salary for additional clarification.

[image]
You could also think of the range as 'up to', so users know if they make greater than 30k, but less than 40k, they are viewing rates *up to 40k.*

Let me know if I've missed the mark, and I'll update to the best I can.